# How to navigate between two View Controllers on firing events in separate View Controller?

Tags: swift, uiviewcontroller, push

I have a StoryBoard of 3 different View Controllers (VC1,VC2,VC3).So how could I push view controller from VC1 to VC2 on in calling a method from VC3 ?

Comment: For me, I don't get it... tapping a button in VC3 means that you are in VC3, so logically speaking, you should push from VC3 to VC1 or VC2. so what's the case?

Comment: Currently I am in VC3 .Tapping on button I want to perform a action at  VC1 so that it will push to VC2

Comment: Why just do not perform that action from vc3?

Comment: Yes .I need to perform push action from VC3

Answer (score 0):

Create a method in your VC1 class for push operation

```
   func pushfromVC1toVC2 ()
    {
    let VC2Obj = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("Identifier") as? VC2
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(VC2Obj!, animated: true)

    }



 Call the above method from your VC3 class

VC3buttonObj.addTarget(self, action: #selector(VC1.pushfromVC1toVC2), forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
```

Comment: self.navigationcontroller?.pushViewController is getting nil value